# the plugin.sbt can not add more than one plugins.

Tags: plugins, build, playframework-2.0, sbt

I use sbt with playframework and activator to build a webapp.
my sbt version is 0.13.0

I change the plugin.sbt file to:

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.4.0")
```

and then the error is:

```
F:\mysource\play-slick>sbt
F:\mysource\play-slick\project\plugins.sbt:9: error: eof expected but ';' found.

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.4.0")
^
[error] Error parsing expression.  Ensure that settings are separated by blank lines.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

I want to know how to add more than one SbtPlugin in plugins.sbt?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `.sbt` files, you must have a blank line between settings (note the error message, `Ensure that settings are separated by blank lines.`).  So, it should be:

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.4.0")
```

For more details on `.sbt` files, see http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Getting-Started/Basic-Def.html.